# TFS 2015 How Do I Get More Than Two Changesets Showing

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, changeset

In TFS 2015 when I view Timeline Tracking only a maximum of two changesets displays even though I have more changesets in the merge.  It seems that only the first and last changeset will appear.  I would like to see all changesets.  Is there a way to configure TFS 2015 so I can see all changesets when looking at merge history via Timeline Tracking?

Answer (score 0):

It will display all the changest related by default. You can see screenshot below from my TFS.
[image]

Changeset4 7 9 (There are three different folders)

Maybe the changeset which you tracked is only including two changests. You can double check it through Hierarchy Tracking.

[image] [image]

If it is the first situation as above,the view of Timeline Tracking including only two changesets  is normal.

Comment: So the problem for me is that it does not seem to work that way.  If I have several changesets in a merge, it only shows the first and last one not all of them.